# Can't get my module layout to work

Tags: module, layout

I'm just trying to test my module by adding some text to the homepage and I can't seem to get this to work. I'm on Magento 1.7.0.2. Magento is aware of my module, I already checked that.

Here is my config:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
<modules>
    <MyPackage_MyModule>
        <version>1.0.0</version>
    </MyPackage_MyModule>
</modules>
<global>
    <blocks>
        <mymodule>
            <class>MyPackage_MyModule_Block</class>
        </mymodule>
    </blocks>
</global>
<frontend>
    <layout>
        <updates>
            <mymodule>
                <file>mymodule.xml</file>
            </mymodule>
        </updates>
    </layout>
</frontend>
</config>
```

Here is what I'm trying to add to the Default Handle, code is in mymodule.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout>
<default>
    <reference name="content">
        <block type="core/text" name="redundant">
            <action method="setText"><text>Hello Again</text></action>
        </block>
    </reference>
</default>
</layout>
```

Comment: I copypasted your code in an empty Magento installation (1.7.0.2), works fine for me. Things I would check:
- Layout cache on?
- code pool is correctly configured?
- echo Mage::getConfig()->getXmlString(), can you see your configuration there?

Comment: huh, well I flushed the cache. I see my module listed in System > Config > Advanced. Where do I put the Mage::getConfig code?

Comment: codepool is set to local

Comment: Is config.xml under app/code/local/MyPackage/MyModule/etc/? Where did you place mymodule.xml? Is your theme correctly configured and selected in backend?

Comment: I created a theme under app>design>frontend>default. I went to system design and clicked 'add change design' and picked my theme which correctly shows in magento now. I added a folder to app>design>frontend> called layout and put my mymodule.xml file in there.

Comment: I also just tried adding mymodule.xml to app>design>frontend>base>default>layout and that didn't work either. I'm expecting to see the text Hello Again on the home page under the 'Home Page' title

Comment: sorry, also yes config.xml is in app/locale/MyPackage/MyModule/etc/

Comment: app/locale/? Or app/code/local/?

Comment: oh, app/locale my install didn't have a app/code/local. That was it! thanks. If you want to put your answer in, I'll mark it. I appreciate your time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check if your module configuration is correctly stored under

```
app/code/local/MyPackage/MyModule/etc/config.xml
```